# How to rotate an arrow label in tikz-cd

Tags: rotating, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have a commutative diagram with a vertical isomorphism, and am currently using a Tilde a one of its labels.

```
\ar[d, "\sim"', "\phi^1"]
```

The intent would be clearer if I rotated the Tilde 90 degrees. Is there an easy way to do that in tikz-cd without rotating the other label?

Comment: I got the correct output with the syntax `\arrow[u, "\sim" {anchor=south, rotate=90}]`, but entering a comma after `"\sim"` yields an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply styles to labels in `tikz-cd`. Usually they would be like `"\sim" draw`, while with multiple options, they would need to be enclosed by braces. However, I'm inexplicably getting an error in that case. So I worked around the problem using `\tikzset` styles.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
    labl/.style={anchor=south, rotate=90, inner sep=.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \ar[d, "\sim" labl, "\phi^1"] \\
b 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```